# Indexing an array in .data faults with an address a lot higher than the array

Tags: arrays, pointers, assembly, x86, masm

My homework to the change values inside an array in MASM, swapping pairs.

```
array[0] = array[1]
array[1] = array[0]
array[2] = array[3]
array[3] = array[2]
```

and so on....

I have abandoned using the `var1` and `var2` variables because I can't seem to get them to work. I have

```
.data
; add data here
array01 DWORD 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600
var1 DWORD ?
var2 DWORD ?

.code
main PROC
    mov edi, OFFSET array01         ; 1: EDI = address of array01
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF array01       ; 2: initialize loop counter
    mov eax, 0                      ; 3: sum =0

L1:                                 ; 4: Mark beginning of loop
    mov eax, [edi]                  ; 5: Get var1
    add edi, TYPE array01           ; 6: increment index
    mov ebx, [edi]                  ; 7: Get var2
    sub edi, TYPE array01           ; 8: decrement to get index to point to the right location

    mov array01[edi], ebx           ; 9: Change array01[i] to var1
    add edi, TYPE array01           ; 10: increment index
    mov array01[edi], eax           ; 11: Change array01[i] to var1
    loop L1                         ; 12: repeats until ecx is 0

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
End main
```

My problem is at instruction 9. It's giving me an error

> Unhandled exception at 0x007C1032 in Assignment_03.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00F88004.

From the debugger, my EDI = `007C4000`, and `&array01` is at `0x007C4000`, **matching each other but not the data address reported for the fault.**  (My EIP = `007C1032`, the code address of the faulting instruction.)

An earlier run had `Exception thrown at 0x00171029 in Assignment_03.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x002E8000.`
I understand that it's telling me I'm accessing something I'm not allowed to but I don't know how to fix it.

---

I have tried `mov [numList+ebx],dh` from
https://termspar.wordpress.com/2019/10/12/x86-assembly-swap-array-elements/  But I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong? Can you please explain the solution. To be clear I don't want an answer to my homework. I want help in changing a value in an array.

`mov dword ptr [array01], 700` works to change the first element, but indexing with EDI isn't working.

Comment: 0x002E8000 is the first address in a new page, so somehow your loop went too many iterations, or your pointer got incremented too much some other way?   Or `.data` wasn't writeable in the first place?  It's not usual for the start of the `.data` section to be close to the end of a page; I'd expect it to be at or near the start.  What do you see for the address of `array01`?  And when you single-step, does your loop fault on the first iteration, or somehow run many iterations?  What's ECX doing?  It should be counting down from 5.

Comment: *I have abandoned using the var1 and var2 variables because I can't seem to get them to work.*  Good; you want registers for loop counters and temporaries, not more static storage!  Also, `mov eax, [edi]` / `mov edx, [edi+4]` / store reversed / `add edi, 8` would seem a lot easier than 2 adds and a sub (which only go forward by a net distance of one `TYPE array01`, by 4, so that's one element, not two.)

Comment: When I single step I get a fault on the first iteration.
ECX is counting down form 5

Comment: I'm also running this on an AMD processor. I don't know if that will make a difference. I got a computer from school that has an Intel chip that the teacher gave me to use for the semester. Don't know if that would make a difference.

Comment: Sounds like your `.data` section ended up read-only somehow!  That's weird, `.data` implies read-write.  What commands are you using to assemble + link this into an executable?

Comment: AMD64 is 100% compatible with Intel64 for all of these instructions, and for all the baseline x86-64 instructions you're going to use in normal user-space programs.  The Intel / AMD differences other than performance are in a few things the kernel has to care about (like an accidental(?) difference in semantics of a #GP fault in `sysret` returning to user-space with a non-canonical RIP), and stuff like atomicity guarantees for unaligned loads/stores within a cache line.  [What EXACTLY is the difference between intel's and amd's ISA, if any?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38516823)

Comment: I'm just running this in debug mode. Nothing more than hitting `Local Windows Debugger`.

Comment: MASM is a command line program.  Are you running it from within Visual Studio?  Or some other GUI IDE?  IDK if it's possible you could be debugging an old executable that doesn't match your current source code.  Otherwise I'd guess there might be a difference between the source you posted on SO vs. what you're actually testing locally.  Put in another `.data` line right before the `array01` in case there's some weird non-ASCII character on the other line that's breaking something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255494/discussion-between-funlamb-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: BTW, the fun way is `movdqu xmm0, xmmword ptr [array01]` / `pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0b10_11_00_01`  (those are 2-bit indices for 4x 4-byte elements, packed into an 8-bit immediate.  NASM accepts that syntax for binary literals, MASM probably doesn't).  / `movdqu xmmword ptr [array01], xmm0`.  You might need to tell MASM to allow SSE2 vector instructions, but compilers use those by default even in 32-bit code these days.  But obviously using a 16-byte shuffle wouldn't teach you to write loops and use addressing modes (and not add the address to itself, as we discussed in chat.)

Comment: The other fun way is to write 64-bit code and do stuff like `ror qword ptr [rdi], 32` to do a 64-bit rotate by 32 to swap halves of a 64-bit chunk of memory.

Comment: I'm not having any lucky finding a duplicate for the problem of `array01[edi]` when EDI is a pointer instead of an index.  search terms like "site:stackoverflow.com assembly array index adding address twice" are finding questions with unrelated titles, although I'd expect that duplicates will have a title about something else. :/

Comment: Hrm, if we include the debugging details from chat, that `&array01` is at `0x007C4000` but the fault address is `0x00F88004`, and make the title something about accessing an address that's twice what was intended, that could perhaps be something that could get found in the future.

Comment: Can you add your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I guess so, since I didn't find a duplicate.  I was resisting doing so because the actual bug  is so trivial and obvious once spotted.

Comment: This loop has 6 iterations,  last one will exchange last element of `array01` with `var1`.  Maybe after `mov ecx, LENGTHOF array01`, program should have `shr ecx,1`. We just need `3 loops` because OP said swap only `[0]` <=> `[1]`, `[2]` <=> `[3]`, `[4]` <=> `[5]`. After each swap, move to another pair of elements `add edi, TYPE array01`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDI is already a pointer: **use `mov [edi], ebx`.**

`mov array01[edi], ebx` is adding the pointer in EDI to the address of of the array.  That would be correct if EDI was a small number, a byte offset from the start of the array.  But it's not in this case; you put a pointer into EDI with `mov edi, OFFSET array01` before the loop.

That address calculation is like C `int *ptr = array01;`  `array01[ (int)ptr ] = tmp2;` but without scaling by the type width.  In discussion in chat, you found the actual address of `array01` was `0x007C4000` using the debugger, but the fault address was reported as writing to `0x00F88004`.  That was the clue to take a more careful look at exactly what the code is doing.

`0x007C4000 * 2 = 0xF88000`, the fault address.  I don't know where the extra `...4` is coming from.  The first store is after the `sub edi, 4` so should be with EDI back to its original value.  (And memory protection uses 4K page granularity, so if 0xF88004 faulted, 0xF88000 should have faulted in the first iteration, like your debugger is showing you actually happened.)

---

**So why did it fault on the store but not the load?**  You used the correct addressing mode for the loads, `[edi]`, just dereferencing the pointer, not adding another address to it!

At first I was thinking it was odd there was read-only memory at that address, but no, the first access was with the stores.

---

BTW, it would be a lot simpler to load and store from `[edi]` and `[edi+4]`, so your loop only needs one `add edi, 8` to advance to the next pair.  (You're currently going forward 8 and back by 4 every iteration, for a net advance of one 4-byte element.)

You'll have to adjust your loop counter to avoid going off the end; it might be easier to work with a pointer to the end of the array and `cmp /` jb L1`against that, instead of calculating an iteration count for the slow`loop`instruction.  You need to stop even if there's 0 or 1 elements left, like the bottom of a`do{... ; ptr+=8;}while(ptr < endp-4);` where endp is a label at the end of the array.

---

BTW, the fun way is to use SIMD to load 4x 32-bit elements (2 pairs), shuffle them, and store them back.  Since the problem size happens to be 2 pairs in this case, we can drop the loop :P

```
   movdqu xmm0, xmmword ptr [array01]   ; 16-byte load
   pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0b10_11_00_01  ; 2-bit indices for 4x 4-byte elements, packed into an 8-bit immediate.
              ; NASM accepts that syntax for binary literals, MASM probably doesn't
              ; _mm_shuffle_epi32(vec, _MM_SHUFFLE(2,3, 0,1))
   movdqu xmmword ptr [array01], xmm0   ; 16-byte store
```

You might need to tell MASM to allow SSE2 vector instructions. C compilers use those by default even in 32-bit code these days. But obviously using a 16-byte shuffle wouldn't teach you to write loops.

The other fun way is to write 64-bit code and do stuff like `ror qword ptr [rdi], 32` to do a 64-bit rotate by 32 to swap halves of a 64-bit chunk of memory.